# realloc : corrupted data returned

Tags: c, realloc, corrupt-data

I'm trying to read from a file using C and after shrinking the size using `realloc` I get corrupted data. I don't really see what the problem could be.

Here's the function that returns the string :

```
char *read_string(FILE *fichier) {
    char car = 0;
    size_t size = 1;
    char *symbole = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char) * size);
    char *s; 
    size_t len = 0;
    if (!symbole)
        return symbole;
    else
        s = symbole; 
    do {
        car = getc(fichier);
    } while (car != '"' && car != EOF);
    if (car == EOF)
        return EOFP; 
    else {
        car = getc(fichier);
        while (car != '"' ) {
            s[len] = car;
            car = getc(fichier);
            len++;
            if (len == size) {
                symbole = realloc(s, sizeof(char) * (size += 1));
                if (!symbole)
                    return symbole;
                else
                    s = symbole; 
            }
        }
        s[len] = '\0' ;
        symbole = realloc(s, sizeof(char) * len);
        if (!symbole) {
            printf("WTF");
            return symbole;
        } else
            s = symbole;  
        return s;
    }
}
```

My `main` function is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fichier = NULL;
    fichier = fopen("C:/Users/Nabila K/Documents/test.json", "r");

    if ((fichier != NULL)) {
        while (feof(fichier) == 0) {
            char *test = read_string(fichier);
            if (test == NULL) {
                printf("test == NULL\n");
                exit(1);
            } else
            if (test == EOFP) {
            } else {
                printf("%s\n", test);
                free(test);
            } 
        } 
        fclose(fichier);   
    } else {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

My json file looks something like this :

```
{
    "KARIM BENNI" : {
       "2017-08-07 09:50:50" : {
          "Anomalie" : {
            "description" : "Test",
            "theme" : "Engins mobiles"
          },
          "date" : "2017-08-07",
          "date_now" : "2017-08-07 09:50:50",
          "entite" : "USINE LAMINAGE A FROID",
          "etat" : "Cree",
          "nb_personne" : 2,
          "temps" : 5,
          "visiteur" : "KARIM BENNI",
          "visite" : "AHMED RABII",
          "zone" : "COUPE"
       }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Two things you need to look out for: First of all [`getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an `int`. This is important for the `EOF` check. Secondly I recommend you read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). When you fixed those problems then I recommend you to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: `'\0'` must be included in the `size`(`len`).

Comment: `symbole = realloc(s, sizeof(char) * (size += 1));` - Please make this two lines of code. Makes debugging easier and the code more readable

Comment: Hasn't a very similar question with very similar source code been asked recently?

Comment: `sizeof(char) * (size += 1)` -- oh come on.

Comment: @Groo i changed it to `sizeof(char) * (size *= 2)` but i still get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- `char car = 0;` is incorrect: you must define `car` as `int` to correctly distinguish all values returned by `getc()`, especially `EOF`.
- `while (feof(fichier) == 0)` is always wrong. Learn why there: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)
- `EOFP` is not defined, you should probably use `NULL` instead for more clarity.
- the final `realloc()` to *shrink* the allocated block is one byte too short. You must keep `len+1` bytes for `len` characters **plus** the null terminator.

Here is a simplified and corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char EOFP[1];   /* special value used to signal end of file */

char *read_string(FILE *file) {
    int c;
    size_t size, len;
    char *symbol;
    char *s;

    while ((c = getc(file)) != '"') {
        if (c == EOF)
            return EOFP;
    }
    size = 16;
    len = 0;
    symbol = malloc(size);
    if (symbol == NULL) {
        /* allocation failure */
        return NULL;
    }
    while ((c = getc(file)) != '"') {
        if (c == EOF) {
            /* premature end of file in the middle of a string */
            free(symbol);
            return EOFP;
        }
        if (len + 2 < size) {
            size += size;
            s = realloc(symbol, size);
            if (s == NULL) {
                /* allocation failure */
                free(symbol);
                return NULL;
            }
            symbol = s;
        }
        symbol[len++] = c;
    }
    symbol[len] = '\0';
    s = realloc(symbol, len + 1);
    return s ? s : symbol;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *file = fopen("C:/Users/Nabila K/Documents/test.json", "r");
    if (file != NULL)) {
        char *test;
        while ((test = read_string(file)) != EOFP) {
            if (test == NULL) {
                printf("test == NULL\n");
                exit(1);
            } else {
                printf("%s\n", test);
                free(test);
            }
        } 
        fclose(file);   
    } else {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- Parsing the full JSON syntax for strings would be required if the strings can contain escaped characters such as `\"` or `\n`, `\\` etc.

Comment: I defined EOFP like this #define EOFP ((void *)1). Is this correct ?

Comment: @NabilaK `#define EOFP ((char *)1)` would be better, but it's still a bit hacky.

Comment: @NabilaK: Such a definition is not recommended, you could either return `NULL` for both end of file and any error condition, as `fgets()` does too, or you could define `EOFP` as a global `char EOFP[1];`

Comment: @EdHeal: not really. `char EOFP[1];` defines an array whose address is different from anything else, whereas `char *EOFP = "";` defines a pointer whose value may be identical to that of other empty strings in the program (although different from any allocated object returned by `read_string()`).

Comment: I have a question : why didn't you shrink the symbol before returning it ?

Comment: @NabilaK: I do: `s = realloc(symbol, len + 1); return s ? s : symbol;` If `realloc()` succeeds, I return `s` and if it fails I return `symbol` which is still valid.